# Export certificates and private key from Windows 10 certificate store which is deployed through Active Directory

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, windows-10, windows-server

I have deployed certificate and private key using AD group policy which deployed certificate and private key to the client machine. When I tried to export the certificate and private key from the client machine, the private key export option was disabled. I have enabled the private key export option when imported to the AD group policy. But that didn't help me to export the private key from the client machine. Certificates export worked well from the client machine without the key.

I would like to export this certificate and key from the client machine (export in any format). Can anyone help to do this?

Thanks in Advance.